# How to set encoding for content in XWalkView.load(baseUrl, content)

Tags: android, encoding, crosswalk-runtime

I try to load the content string with the Greek word. And the word displayed in wrong encoding.

I use the demo project [CrosswalkDemo](https://github.com/dougdiego/CrosswalkDemo), all project files are in UTF-8 encoding. I made the following changes:

1) changed version of xwalk_core_library in the file

```
\app\build.gradle
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:12.41.296.5'
```

2) added permission in the file

```
\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In the folder /mnt/sdcard/html/ I have the file NotoSerif-Regular.ttf

and try to do the following in file MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private XWalkView xWalkWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    xWalkWebView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
    xWalkWebView.load(
            "file:///mnt/sdcard/html/",
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />" +
            "<style>" +
            "@font-face {" +
            "font-family: 'NotoSerif';" +
            "src: url('NotoSerif-Regular.ttf');" +
            "font-weight: normal;" +
            "font-style: normal;" +
            "}" +
            "body {font-family: 'NotoSerif';}" +
            "</style>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body> Test 12345 δοκιμή </body>" +
            "</html>");

    // turn on debugging
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
}
```

The font is loaded correctly. But the Greek word "δοκιμή" displayed in wrong encoding.

A similar test with Android's WebView is successful.

What should be done for correct encoding?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for adding the demo project.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed as part of [XWALK-3571](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-3571)

And this is the commit itself: [Pull Request 3288](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/pull/3288/files)